# Getting horizontal scroll when moving the elements even though they're not overflowing

Tags: html, css

so I'm doing the contact section of my website and everytime I left:15em the wrapper of the textboxes and labels, I get a horizontal scroll. How can I move the elements without getting the scroll?

```js
function scrollDown() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 600);
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Segoe UI', 'sans-serif';
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a{
    padding: .3em;
    color: #000;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
    width: 74px;
    height: 21px;
    left: 130px;
    top: 71px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
}

li a:hover{
    color: #e48257;
    transition: .3s;
}

.title{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 462px;
    height: 168px;
    left: 171px;
    top: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #252525;
}
span{
    color:#e48257
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 455px;
    left: 763px;
    top: 190px;
}
button:nth-of-type(2){
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 45px;
    left: 310px;
    top: 526px;
    background: #333C54;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
}
button:nth-of-type(1){
    position: absolute;
    width: 127px;
    height: 45px;
    left: 171px;
    top: 526px;
    border: 1px solid #333C54;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    
}
.about-us{
    position: relative;
    top: 54em;
}
.about-us-breadcrumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 21px;
    left: 171px;
    top: 23px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #8E8E8E;
}
.about-us-text{
    position: absolute;
width: 530px;
height: 210px;
left: 171px;
top: 60px;

font-family: Roboto;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 42px;

color: #000000;

}

*::selection{
    background-color: #e48257;
    color:white;
}
.about-us-illustration{
    position: absolute;
    width: 418px;
    height: 72px;
    left: 851px;
    top: 90px;
    
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 75px;
    
    color: #333C54;
    
}
s{
    color: #333C54;
}

@keyframes strike{
    0%   { width : 0; }
    100% { width: 100%; }
}
s::after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  animation-name: strike;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  background-color: #333C54;
}

.contact-us{
    position: relative;
    top: 90em;
}
.have-any-questions{
    position: absolute;
    width: 135px;
    height: 21px;
    left: 653px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #8E8E8E;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.contact-us-title{
    position: absolute;
    width: 345px;
    height: 73px;
    left: 570px;
    top: 30px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 75px;
    color: #333C54;
}

input{
    border: #000 1px solid;
    width: 390px;
    height: 40px;
}
.name .email .number{
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    top: 15em;
}
.form{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 15em;
    left: 15em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Code Playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="center">
        <p class="title">Where coding <br> is <span>fun</span></p>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button href="#" onclick="scrollDown()">Learn More</button>
            <button href="#">Start</button>
        </div>
        
        <img src="illustration.png" alt="illustraton">
    </div>
    <section class="about-us">
        <p class="about-us-breadcrumb">About Us</p>
        <p class="about-us-text">Code Playground is a non-profit organization that helps aspiring programmers improve their coding skills by playing fun and exciting games. </p>
        <p class="about-us-illustration"><span><s>Learn to Code</s><br>Code to Learn!</span></p>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-us">
        <p class="have-any-questions">Have any questions?</p>
        <p class="contact-us-title">Contact Us!</p>
        <div class="form">
            <p class="name">Name:</p><br>
            <input type="text" class="name"><br>
            <p class="email">Email:</p><br>
            <input type="text" class="name"><br>
            <p class="number">Contact Number: </p><br>
            <input type="text" class="name"> 
        </div>
        
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a bad code, sorry, this is my first time doing this. Really, really, **sorry**.
This is some text bc stackoverflow think that my quesion is mostly code but I can't really add more text this is all I can add sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div with the "form" class has `display: block`, which means its width is the same as its container's constraints, in this case, the whole page.

But then you moved it `left: 15em` and it "pushed" the div to the right, beyond the page width.

There are two solutions with minimal change:

You can change it to `display: inline-block`

You can set an accurate width using calc() `width: calc(100% - 15em)`